# estimation of a moment for the sum with Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, inequality

Let $x\in R_+^n$ and let $b_i, i=1, \ldots, n$ be $(0,1)$ Bernoulli random variables with $P(b_i=1)=p$. Denote $S=\sum_{i=1}^n x_ib_i$. For $q\geq 2$ estimate from above
$$
E\left|S\right|^q
$$

Comment: Is $q$ assumed an integer $\geq 2$, or any real?

Comment: $q$ is any real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are asked to apply [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for convex function $\varphi(x) = x^{q/2}$:
$$
       \mathbb{E}\left(S^q\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\varphi(S^2)\right)  \geqslant \varphi\left( \mathbb{E}(S^2) \right) = \mathbb{E}\left(S^2\right)^{q/2}
$$
$$
   \mathbb{E}(S^2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_i x_j \mathbb{E}\left(b_i b_j\right) = p^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2 + p(1-p) \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2
$$
where the last equality is obtained by considering $i\not= j$ and $i=j$ separately.

Comment: Thsnk you, but I wanted an estimate from above, i.e. $E(S^q)\leq ...$

Comment: @Alex A trivial estimate from above is to set all $b_k=1$ and use monotonicity, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(S^q) < \left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right)^q$.

Comment: Yes, but its too simple. I've been asked to uase some probabilistic inequality to obtein something better then that...

Comment: @Sasha why did you use the convex function $\phi(x)=x^{q/2}$ instead of just $\phi(x)=x^q$.

Comment: Because $x^\alpha$ is convex for $\alpha \geq 1$, and $setting $\alpha=\frac{q}{2}$ is the best we can do.